# psycopg2 error : DatabaseError with status PGRES_TUPLES_OK and no message from the libpq

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql-11

Libs being used:

- Postgresql-11
- psycopg2-binary==2.8.2
- celery==4.3.0

I have tried upgrading psycopg2.

This will not occur if i put time sleep and try to it.(But, that is wrong way of approach i guess.)

```py
db_config = {
    'dbname': "test",
    'user': "*******",
    'password': "*******",
    'host': "*******",
    'port': 5432,
    'cursor_factory': RealDictCursor
}

pool = ThreadedConnectionPool(
    minconn=1, maxconn=8, **db_config
)

def get(self, query, args=None):
    conn = self._get_connection()
    curr = conn.cursor()
    try:
        curr.execute(query, vars=(args or ()))
        result = curr.fetchone()
    except psycopg2.ProgrammingError as error:
        print(error.pgcode)
        raise error
    finally:
        self._put_connection(conn)
    return result
```

Throws below error when I query to table.

> [2019-08-08 10:03:47] INFO  test_run.py  Line: 51  2019-08-08 10:03:47.040447.
>
> [2019-08-08 10:03:47] INFO  request.py   Line: 43  querying to table.
>
> [2019-08-08 10:03:47] INFO  test_run.py  Line: 51  2019-08-08 10:03:47.074309
>
> [2019-08-08 10:03:47] INFO  request.py   Line: 43  querying to table
>
> [2019-08-08 10:03:47] INFO  test_run.py  Line: 51  2019-08-08 10:03:47.094708
>
> [2019-08-08 10:03:47] INFO  request.py   Line: 43  querying to table
>
> [2019-08-08 10:03:47] INFO  test_run.py  Line: 51  2019-08-08 10:03:47.137223
>
> [2019-08-08 10:03:47] INFO  request.py   Line: 43  querying to table
>
> [2019-08-08 10:03:47] INFO  test_run.py  Line: 51  2019-08-08 10:03:47.160482
>
> [2019-08-08 10:03:47] INFO  request.py   Line: 43  querying to table
>
> [2019-08-08 10:03:47] INFO  test_run.py  Line: 51  2019-08-08 10:03:47.180747
>
> [2019-08-08 10:03:47] INFO  request.py   Line: 43  querying to table
>
> [2019-08-08 10:03:47] INFO  test_run.py  Line: 51  2019-08-08 10:03:47.202793
>
> [2019-08-08 10:03:47] INFO  request.py   Line: 43  querying to table
>
> [2019-08-08 10:03:47] INFO  test_run.py  Line: 51  2019-08-08 10:03:47.347288
>
> [2019-08-08 10:03:47] INFO  request.py   Line: 43  querying to table
>
> [2019-08-08 10:03:47] INFO  test_run.py  Line: 51  2019-08-08 10:03:47.386351
>
> [2019-08-08 10:03:47] INFO  test_run.py  Line: 108  error code : None
>
> [2019-08-08 10:03:47] INFO  test_run.py  Line: 109  Error: no results to fetch
>
> [2019-08-08 10:03:47] ERROR  signal.py  Line: 293  Signal handler  raised`enter code here`: DatabaseError('error with status PGRES_TUPLES_OK and no message from the libpq')